# Issue with image fading in on load

Tags: jquery, html, modernizr, jquery-masonry, html5boilerplate

As things have cleared up lately, I started working on my portfolio again. It's still very fresh but I could use some help with jquery .load() of images.

http://progress.patrikarvidsson.com/

I'm using jQuery with html5boilerplate; on top of this I have Masonry and Lightbox. I don't suspect the code for the greyscale stuff is the culprit so I won't include it here. Below is the top of my scripts.js file (after the greyscale-code follows).

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".thumb img").bind("load", function () { $(this).fadeIn('slow'); });
```

Html looks like this (structure still follows html5boilerplate. JS-files are after, but modernizr are before)

```
<div class="block">
    <a href="titlehighres.jpg" class="thumb" title="title"><img src="img/thumbs/titleSmall.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

The fadeIn() works, but not as I want it. Images are loaded first, after which they are autmatically hidden when document is loaded and then fadeIn takes effect. You can probably see it if you visit the link above. Basically, for me it looks like this.

```
Page load
Images loads with color
jQuery hides images
jQuery fadeIn desaturated images
```

This happens every time I hit refresh. Note that this is in Chrome, fadein doesn't work at all in Firefox but I haven't tested this on my other computer yet. In the end, I can't figure out what the problem is.

**Update**

I have decided to use css3-animation instead. It works pretty well but I am yet to see how it looks in older browsers.

Although, I'm still curious to why this issue happens. So an answer is still encouraged!

Answer (score 1):

Try hiding the colour images in CSS. They will then not be shown on page load:

```
.img_grayscale { display: none; }
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't solve the loading of colored image before jQuery wants to fade them in issue. It also made the hover-function non-functional.

If I can, I'd rather not use css to hide elements as I want viewers without javascript to be able to see the portfolio as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the `opacity` of all your images to something really low -- ever so barely seen, but retaining their dimensions -- on `document.ready`.

```
// document ready
$(function() {

    // reduce opacity
    $('.img_wrapper img').css('opacity',0.01);

    // fade in the grayscale images
    $(".img_grayscale").bind("load", function () { $(this).fadeIn('slow'); });

});
```

Alternatively, just hide the images via Javascript -- that way, noscript viewers can still see your images, as you noted above.

```
    $('.img_wrapper img').hide();
```

Comment: It still hides the images after they are rendered and shown. Same with opacity, it happens after - even on document ready.